# Bash script to open tmux but can't see username

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tmux

I have a bash script that starts a tmux session with some monitoring tools, and have a cronjob that runs it on startup; however, I can't see the usual prefix to my commands, and I can't use any arrow keys.

[image]

Normally it should look like this:

[image]

(the actual script)

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/ubuntu/

tmux start-server

tmux new-session -d -s "0" bash
tmux selectp -t 1
tmux splitw -h -p 50
tmux selectp -t 2
tmux splitw -v -p 50
tmux selectp -t 3
tmux send-keys "htop" C-m

# Select pane 1
tmux selectp -t 0
tmux attach-session -t "0"
tmux detach
```

What went wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cron job started sh or dash instead of bash (Ubuntu made a difference between bash and sh... I don't know if it is still the case).
You should be able to check this with a `ps ux` when your cron-tmux is running.

If a real bash was started, maybe it didn't `source ~/.bashrc`: try `/bin/bash -i`, or manually source it in your script.

Also, within a cron job, the environment is usually minimal. Type `env` in your tmux session to see what is available, this could give you a clue.

If your cron is run as root (you didn't mention, so I assumed as user), his bashrc may be minimal or inexistant, hence the ugly cmdline.

Comment: The OP says that Ctrl-C doesn't work, which is a function of the tty driver, not of the shell. Something else is going on there.

Comment: @pizdelect My mistake, Ctrl-C does work, just the arrow keys don't